# Noun for something that is randomly chosen?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Example:

> Since the murderer didn't know the victim, the detectives assumed the
>   murder was a [...].

This is just an example, though, I'm not looking for a word for that kind of crime. Just a noun that means "something that is randomly chosen".

Comment: Are you looking for a noun?  I would use an adjective (namely *random*).

Comment: janoChen, please show the research you do. You are doing your own research, aren't you?

Comment: Well, I'm asking for "something that is randomly chosen". I didn't know how to research that. Searching for "random" on Thesaurus would just yield an adjective. Not a "thing".

Comment: @AndyT Oh, I didn't realize. I thought the "something" in the title implied that. Sorry about that.

Comment: In the context of a murder committed by a robber it might be better to say something like "the victim did not appear to be targeted".  If the killer set out to kill someone, "the victim was apparently chosen at random".

Comment: This is just typical of your behaviour. You always, always award the highest upvoted answer. You wanted a noun, but instead you  award an adjective because it is the highest upvoted answer. Never mind it doesn't fit in your example sentence, otherwise *why* award "arbitary"?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Oh, well I just made it arbitrariness instead. Okay, I'll uncheck the question and wait for a while.

Comment: @janoChen - If you're still waiting for an answer, I highly recommend Brian Hitchcock's answer of "happenstance."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- happenstance (n)  A chance happening or event.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/happenstance?s=t

- Fortuitous (adj)
  Happening or produced by chance; accidental

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fortuitous?s=t

Comment: A random choice is not a chance or accidental occurrence.

Comment: *Fortuitous* is generally used to describe a measure of (good) fortune, so the context needs to be considered carefully (e.g. it doesn't work in the asker's example).

Comment: _fortunate_ necessarily entails good fortune. The primary sense of _fortuitous_ does not. But you do have a point; most people would conflate these two distinct words, and would be loathe to call a murder "fortuitous".

Comment: This should have been the answer awarded. The OP wanted a noun, and happenstance is exactly that, it also expresses an event that is not planned or premeditated.

Answer (score 14):

Something chosen at random can be called *arbitrary*.

> [arbitrary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/arbitrary) (adj.) - Based on random choice or personal whim, rather than any reason or system

Comment: "The detectives assumed the murder was an arbitrary." ?

Comment: The title was changed. A noun was not specified when I had answered.

Comment: Then you get a cookie for using the word that the sentence should be rearranged to fit.

Comment: I suppose you could use **arbitrariness** as the noun form, but I think it sounds weird, personally.

Answer (score 10):

I can think of

> [indiscriminately](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/indiscriminately) - In a random manner; unsystematically:

or maybe even a less profound alternative like *unselective* or *aimless*, depending on the context

I think *indiscriminately* might be a better choice than arbitrary, because I believe the latter has a connotation of personal choice based on a mood. I am, however, not too sure about this and might be corrected accordingly.

Comment: _Arbitrary_ can also be used without any implication of actual volition, as in mathematics (let a be an arbitrarily close to b).

Comment: Good one.  You might also want to mention the adjective form "indiscriminate".

Answer (score 5):

**Randomness** is the [noun form of *random*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/random), but it doesn't work for usage as "such and such was a randomness".

You can use it in the phrase **act of randomness**, which may be what you're looking for. Unfortunately I think "of randomness" is essentially just an adjective, and therefore it might not be any better than the many synonyms of *random* that have been given as answers.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

> a chance occurrence

or

> a random act

or

> a crime of opportunity

Answer (score 2):

**a shot in the the dark:** a random conjecture
**throw of the dice:** a risky attempt to do or achieve something

If you want a noun for *"something that is randomly chosen"*, you could use the noun form of chosen - **random/arbitrary choice**. Or to be precise, in probability, the result of a random experiment is called an **outcome**.

Answer (score 1):

I think ***[accidental](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/accidental)*** can convey the 'random' aspect you are referring to:

> - Happening by chance, unintentionally, or unexpectedly. (ODO)

- the murder was an accident, or accidental.

Comment: A murder is by definition a deliberate act, not an accident.

Comment: @phoog - in the *specific example* of the murder, **accident** might not work, but it does work for **random**. e.g. "I needed a drink of water so rang a doorbell and completely *by accident* picked my history teacher's door".

Comment: @phoog - Outside of war (and war-like scenarios like gang violence) I think you will find that most murders are accidental, in that the killer did not set out with intent to kill someone.

Comment: @HotLicks in US law, at least, homicide without intent is usually *manslaughter.*  It is my understanding that other jurisdictions similarly have lesser crimes for unintentional killing.

Comment: @phoog - The thing is that if you walk into a liquor store and try to hold it up and the clerk resists and you shoot and kill him, it's murder, even if you had no intention of killing anyone when you walked in, and even if the gun did, in fact, go off accidentally in the struggle.

Comment: @HotLicks point taken.

Comment: *Accident* suggests lack of control or intelligent design rather than randomness. The asker wants to describe something that is intentionally chosen at random, not something that happened naturally at random.

Answer (score 1):

How about [caprice](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caprice):

> a sudden, impulsive, and seemingly unmotivated notion or action

Comment: A caprice isn't the object that is chosen, it is the act.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of murder, a good adjective is *senseless*. A *senseless murder* is one that occurred for no particular explanatory reason. For example, if a mugger were to demand someone's wallet and the victim fought back, we could understand why he might shoot the victim. But if he shoots the victim after receiving the wallet just because he can, then that is *senseless*.

See [senseless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/senseless) (meaning *c*)

> : done or happening for no reason ; destitute of, deficient in, or contrary to sense: as
>
> a :  unconscious
>
> b :  foolish, stupid
>
> **c :  meaningless**

Answer (score 1):

*A strong word, generally left to the realm of science : "stochasticity*".

> Since the murderer didn't know the victim, the detectives assumed the
>   murder was a ***[stochasticity](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/stochasticity)***.
>
> - the quality of lacking any predictable order or plan
> - Synonyms:haphazardness, noise, ***[randomness](http://www.lexipedia.com/english/stochasticity)***

The term stochastic occurs in a wide variety of professional or academic fields to describe events or systems that are unpredictable due to the influence of a random variable. The word "stochastic" comes from the Greek word στόχος (stokhos, "aim"). ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic))

Answer (score 1):

**vagary** /vəˈgɛər i, ˈveɪ gə ri/ noun —[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vagary)

> 1.an unpredictable or erratic action, occurrence, course, or instance:
>   *the vagaries of weather; the vagaries of the economic scene.*

Looking up [whimsy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whimsy) led me to vagary.

Comment: I think it shares the same Latin root as *vagrant*, which is what the cops probably thought they were.

Answer (score 1):

Items (but not usually people) are sometimes referred to as **sundries** if they are haphazard, miscellaneous, or otherwise not important enough to refer to by name.
As per the Oxford dictionaries:

> **sundries** *noun* (plural sundries)
>
> Various items not important enough to be mentioned individually:
>   "a drugstore selling magazines, newspapers, and sundries".

---

> **sundry** *adjective*
>
> [ATTRIBUTIVE]
>   Of various kinds; several:
>   "prawn and garlic vol-au-vents and sundry other delicacies".

Source: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sundry

Answer (score 0):

***Opportunistic*** describes crimes committed without a specific target, based on opportunities which arise, rather than being individually planned. In your case this would suggest that to commit murder was the primary goal of the crime, as opposed to a "robbery gone wrong".

In the case of murder, it's not often going to be the case that a murder is "opportunistic" unless the criminal is very depraved indeed. I believe most murders either target a particular individual the murderer have a motive for killing, or are unplanned consequences of other crimes such as burglary or robbery or kidnapping which have "gone wrong".

Comment: *Opportunistic* is not related to *random* in any way.

Comment: @AndyT, I do not know why you think that!.

Comment: Because *opportunistic* means *taking opportunities*, it does not mean *doing things at random*. Example of a random crime: "I want to rob someone. Eenie meenie minie mo... I pick that guy!". Example of an opportunistic crime: "I'm off down the shops on my bike. Oh, that guy has left his phone on the table, let's nick it and cycle off". In this second example the guy is picked because he left his phone in an accessible place; the thief therefore used *logic* which is **not *random***.

Comment: @AndyT, I don't think you know what random means. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/random Random means unpredictable, it does not mean uncaused, and it certainly doesn't require anyone to recite a rhyme or use any "random method of choosing between alternatives". An opportunistic crime will occur randomly because opportunities occur randomly.

Comment: Nice link, exactly what I've been consulting. Let's see what it says: "proceeding, made, or **occurring without definite** aim, **reason**, or pattern". Why did the thief steal that guy's phone? Was there a **reason**? Yes, it was because he left his phone on the table.

Comment: Your argument that opportunities occur randomly holds no weight. Spots on a teenager's face occur at random, does that mean we can use *spotty* as a synonym for *random*? No. (Just to check - although the OP didn't use the word *synonym*, you do realise that he's looking for one, right? And my argument is that *opportunistic* is not a synonym of *random*.)

Comment: @andyT, Who said opportunistic was a synonym of random? I didn't. The question didn't ask for synonyms, it asked for words which described random crimes. Adding in some information about the world we see that crimes which are random are likely to be opportunistic also. Next: The key word in the dictionary definition is "or". Any of those would make it random, you don't need all of them, you only need one. It occurs without pattern so it is random. Finally: I am not interested in discussing it any more - I've no objection to you being wrong all day long if it makes you happy.

Comment: And I quote from the original question: "I'm not looking for a word for that kind of crimes". So, no, the question did not ask for "words which described random crimes".  It asked for "something that describes something that is randomly chosen". It just happened to use a crime as an example.

Comment: +1. It might not be a literal fit for the way the question is worded, but this _is_ idiomatic for what OP is trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Is *"a **blind murder**"* fitting your need?

> **[blind](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blind)**
>
> **2.** Lacking perception, awareness, or judgement:
>
> > **2.1** Not controlled by reason:
> >
> > > *they left in blind panic*

Answer (score 0):

> [higgledy-piggledy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/higgledy-piggledy)
>
> adj, adv
>
> 1. in a jumble
>
> n
>
> 2. a muddle

I **admit** it's not the perfect word for what you are describing, but it's really fun to say.

Answer (score 0):

**Happenstance**

> something that happens by chance
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/happenstance

or

**Coincidence**

> a situation in which events happen at the same time in a way that is not planned or expected
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coincidence

Answer (score 0):

**Freak occurrence** ([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/freak))

> A freak occurrence, on the other hand, is not necessarily a bad thing,
>   but connotes something irregular or unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

How about a **lark** or a **whim**?

[Lark](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lark) (as in "on a lark")

1. a merry, carefree adventure; frolic; escapade.
2. innocent or good-natured mischief; a prank.
3. something extremely easy to accomplish, succeed in, or to obtain

[Whim](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whim?s=ts)

1. an odd or capricious notion or desire; a sudden or freakish fancy
2. capricious humor

Answer (score -1):

- uncorrelated
- independent
- unrelated
- nonsequitur

Comment: Hi Steve and welcome to ELU! Please consider adding definitions for each of these words to show why they are an acceptable choice.

Answer (score -1):

> **one-off**
>
> *noun*: *[Something that is not repeated or reproduced](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/one-off)*.

- Police suspect that the murder was a one-off

> It could have been someone else, somewhere else. **The James Bulger murder was a one-off**, and nothing like that will happen again for a long, long time. The Damilola Taylor murder was not. It could happen again next week, next month.
> <sub>[The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/uk/2000/dec/03/ukcrime.race)</sub>

My suggestion doesn't fit neither the OP's title nor the question in the body, **a one-off** is not *random* by any stretch of the imagination,  and it is not *chosen*, but it is a noun which expresses a unique, never-to-be-repeated event or thing.